# Hola Barcelona public transport card bought online

Tags: public-transport, europe, spain, transportation, barcelona

I'm looking on the Barcelona public transport system and it seems to be cheaper if one buys the card online. Here is [their website](https://www.tmb.cat/en/barcelona-fares-metro-bus/tickets-visit-barcelona/barcelona-travel-card-hola-bcn/3-days).

I have two questions in this case:

1. How do I get the card, will it be sent in some way? I'm not in Spain now, I want to use it when I arrive there next month.
2. How the availability will be set? I want the 72 hours one. Will it start the time countdown from the first time I use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [purchasing site for *Hola Barcelona*](https://www.holabarcelona.com/tickets/hola-bcn-barcelona-travel-card), when you purchase the card online, you will be emailed a voucher code which you can use to retrieve the travel card itself at any metro station. They also offer [a video about the process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjAd5LtNkzg) if that is interesting for you.

According to the same site, the card is valid for 72 hours (or your choice of other duration) from "first validation", so, yes, the first time you use it.

Answer (score 5):

you can pick up the card at the [tourist information booth](https://bcnshop.barcelonaturisme.com/shopv3/en/product/947/hola-barcelona-travel-card-.html).

"You can also use your card to travel from Barcelona Airport. You can buy or pick up your card at the tourist information offices at the two terminals."